# Pagination Logic - Vue

Tags: javascript, vue.js, pagination, logic

Hey hopefully someone can help me out, Ive started a new job and my brain has turned to utter crap and seemingly simple tasks are now causing me issues, its like I left my brain at my last job? Anyway I have some pagination that Im trying to build the logic for.

I have a v-for that loops through the data to build the pagination using the index number as the page number. I also know what page number is active and how many total pages. Im using v-if to either show or hide the pagination items. I want to show 8 items at any one time and hide the rest so if page 2 is active, items 2-9 would be shown and rest would be hidden, that part works fine. What im trying to do is when I get towards the end of the list I still want to keep 8 items on screen and the active item just advances i.e so 9 items in total, item 2 is set to active and on screen I can see items 2-9, when I click next I still want to have 8 items on screen (2-9) but now the active item is item 3 and so on. Can this be done using the v-if or am I loosing the plot and trying to achieve the impossible?

```
<div v-for="index in totalPages" :key="index">
              <div
                v-if="
                  index >= activeItem &&
                  index < activeItem + onScreenTotal
                "
                :class="index === activeItem ? 'active' : null"
              >
                {{ index }}
              </div>
            </div>
```

- **totalPages** = total number of pagination items
- **activeItem** = the active page item
- **onScreenTotal** = how many items I want to show on screen at any one time

Answer (score 0):

You can with some `Math.min(..)` and `Math.max(..)` calls, but your template would get really messy. I would recommend moving the logic to a computed property. You start either at the current page, or `this.onScreenTotal` pages before the end, with the edge case that if you have less than `this.onScreenTotal` pages you want to start at page 1 and not 0 or some negative number. You can calculate the end in the same way, except that we will never exceed the number of pages we have.

```
<template v-for="index in visiblePages">
  <div :key="index" :class="{ active: index === activeItem }">
    {{ index }}
  </div>
</template>

// And in your javascript
computed: {
  visiblePages() {
    const pages = [];
    const start = Math.max(1, Math.min(this.activeItem, this.totalPages - this.onScreenTotal));
    const end = Math.min(start + this.onScreenTotal, this.onScreenTotal);

    for (const i = start; i <= end; i++) {
      pages.push(i);
    }

    return pages;
  }
}
```